# Keep div displayed when input inside of it has focus

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
   <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

I have a `div` element with `input` inside of it. Now, this `div` has `display: none` property on it. Now, when I display the `div` (by hovering at another element on my site, not important here), I can now put some text in the `input` element. But when I have focus on that `input`, and I accidentally move my mouse out of the `div` element, this `div` element disappears. Is there any chance that I can keep my `div` element displayed when the `input` has focus no matter where the mouse is?

Edit: After editing Sergio's example, here is the problem I am facing: http://jsfiddle.net/2thMQ/1/ (try typing something in that input field and then move your mouse away)

Comment: Are you showing the `div` with javascript?

Comment: That's very likely. Also, could you show the "not important" part together with the mouseout event?

Comment: No, I don't want to use any javascript for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `input:focus { display:block; }`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2thMQ/)**

Only CSS

```
div:hover input {
    display:block;
}
input:focus {
    display:block;
}
input {
    display:none;
}
```

If you want to style the parent `div` it will be possible in CSS4. So far here is a javascript solution for this:

```
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    inp[i].onfocus = function(){ this.parentNode.style.display='block';}
    inp[i].onblur = function(){ this.parentNode.style.display='none';}
};
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4j5K/)**

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, could you maybe look at this: `http://jsfiddle.net/2thMQ/1/`? My problem is more like in this example. Anyways thank you for your example :)

Comment: @ojek, what you want is a "parent" selector. That function will only be available in CSS4. You can read about it here: http://www.red-team-design.com/meet-the-css4-selectors

Comment: So my solution is the possible without javascript. Do you want help with javascript to it?

Comment: You are welcome. BTW the javascript could be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j4j5K/